# Custom timezone support in Laravel/Lumen

Tags: mysql, laravel, lumen, laravel-5.4

If I'm building a timezone aware Laravel (Lumen) app, where the user may not have control over their database timezone settings, but can provide my app with a custom timezone in the config.

I also need to be able to store timestamps in the database via a direct connection in a third party app (again remember the timezone may be incorrect in the database config) so I'm thinking a unix timestamp would be appropriate so I can use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())` in my third party direct connection.

1. Should I be storing timestamps in unix integer format?
2. What is the best way to support this globally in Laravel since `$table->timestamps();` uses TIMESTAMP
3. How do I ensure date/times are automatically converted to the timezone specified in the Laravel config when I query the database to output json to an API?

***Note: I am not looking to translate to multiple timezones, just the one in the .env***

Current .env

`APP_TIMEZONE=UTC`

Current migration example

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateSharesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('shares', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->string('url', 500);
            $table->string('description', 100);
            $table->integer('hits');
            $table->string('ip_address', 39);

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Current Share model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Share extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['url', 'description', 'ip_address'];

    protected $hidden = ['ip_address'];
}
```

Current controller example

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Share;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ShareController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @SWG\Get(
     *     tags={"Shares"},
     *     path="/shares",
     *     summary="Finds all shares",
     *     description="Returns all shares ",
     *     @SWG\Response(
     *         response=200,
     *         description="A list of all shares"
     *     )
     * )
     */
    public function fetchAll()
    {

        return Share::get();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `config\app.php` instead of `.env`

```
config(['app.timezone' => $timezone]);
```

where `$timezone` is one of these: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

> Should I be storing timestamps in unix integer format?

You could, but iso8601 is litterally an ISO standard, so why not that

> What is the best way to support this globally in Laravel since
>   $table->timestamps(); uses TIMESTAMP

[Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) is a nice way to work with timestamps, adding and substracting time. Use my code above to change the timezones and use them in Carbon.

> How do I ensure date/times are automatically converted to the timezone
>   specified in the Laravel config when I query the database to output
>   json to an API?

That's what Laravel will handle for you if you set the timezone in a session that can be kept between requests or if you pass it alang as an argument every request.

Comment: If I was to use NOW() from my third party direct db connection however that would insert a TIMESTAMP based on the timezone settings of the database. Therefore shouldn't I be storing everything in unix timestamps to ensure that both the third party direct connection, and Laravel insert them in the same "timezone" (UTC).

Comment: I would store everyting as UTC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC
And them on the fly display the timestamps according to the visitors timezone using carbon of you have this information in php or use moment.js as a last resort when you get the info from the browser (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript)

Comment: Just realised I can use `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` from my third party direct connection

Comment: There is no app.php file (config\app.php) in config directory in Lumen then how will we fix this issue ? Thanks in advance.